# Binding checkboxes ( true, false ) with a Map<number, boolean>

Tags: json, angular, checkbox, binding

I have this variable in my component :
`weekdays = { 1:"MON", 2:"TUE", 3:"WED", 4:"THU", 5:"FRI", 6:"SAT", 7:"SUN" };`

I have a JSON-server which contains `price-rules`, a `price-rule` looks like this ( JSON structure ) :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "activity": "Tennis",
    "duration": "60",
    "isIndoor": true,
    "surface": "code",
    "hourStart": "08:00",
    "hourEnd": "18:00",
    "price": "1656",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "weekdays": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6,
      7
    ]
  }
```

So I have a model class `price-rule`, a `price-rule` is exactly like the JSON structure, except the `weekdays` attribute.
In the JSON, `weekdays` is an array of number, but in the model, `weekdays` is a Map `Map<number, boolean>`

I have this in my HTML :

```
<div class="inline" *ngFor="let day of weekdays | keyvalue">
         <nb-checkbox (click)="change(pricerule.id)" [(ngModel)]="pricerule.weekdays.get(+day.key)" status="success" value="{{ isSelected(day.key, pricerule.weekdays) }}">
                    {{ day.value }}
         </nb-checkbox>
 </div>
```

What I am trying to do is to bind each checkboxe to each day of `pricerule.weekdays`. `pricerules.weekdays` is a `Map<number, boolean>`

In the JSON price_rule example, `weekdays` contains all days of the week ( 1 for MON,2 for TUE, ... 7 for SUN ). If I unselect for example the checkbox corresponding to sunday and right after that I apply an update http request to the server, it should look like this :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "activity": "Tennis",
    "duration": "60",
    "isIndoor": true,
    "surface": "code",
    "hourStart": "08:00",
    "hourEnd": "18:00",
    "price": "1656",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "weekdays": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  }
```

And in the model, the value of the KEY 7 has to be false

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngModelChange** event on your checkboxes. Check an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8lyzln)

Comment: can you explain what is $event

Comment: $event is an specific argument for angular elements. It is return a new value for checkboxes. We have to use it because it will fire before ngModel change.